# How do I install wacom drivers for Lenovo X200 tablet on ubuntu 12?

Tags: drivers, lenovo, wacom

So I am newish to linux and I own a Thinkpad 200T by Lenovo and I am trying to get ubuntu 12 to accept the tablet , but so far cannot get it to respond. I Don't know what drivers I need I only tried using software center.  I feel that t he hardware may be disconnected internally and I am not sure of a way to find out without ripping it apart. So my first approach would be to install the correct driver via terminal if I could and see if it takes.  Any suggestions would be great. Again remember I am not a guru with linux I just find that in most applications I enjoy it far more than OSX or windows.  In-fact I hate windows. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse my comment as an answer, I don't have enough reputation to add a comment.

Welcome to the world of Linux based operating systems! Listing your Wacom tablet model will help get you a better answer. If you want to stick with an older operating system you will probably have to install the driver for your tablet from http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page?/ (Depending on your tablet model).

What makes you think the hardware in the laptop may be disconnected internally?

You may also want to consider installing Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10 if possible.